# How to Check for null value in asp.net source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, null

I want to check if Date is null then display a string .
if not null display date.

```
  <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Issue_Date")).ToShortDateString() %>' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also solve it like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" 
           Text='<%# (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Issue_Date")) ? 
                 Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Issue_Date")).ToShortDateString() :
                 "yourStringIfNull") %>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a method in the code-behind:

```
public string DisplayDateTime(object value)
{
  if (value== null)
  {
     return "Date is null";
  }

  return Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToShortDateString();
}
```

then call DisplayDateTime from a page:

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# DisplayDateTime(Eval("Issue_Date")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```